# Standard regarding punctuation in headlines?

Tags: punctuation

What is the standard regarding punctuation in headlines?

Comment: Related: [Punctuation of captions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121551/caption-text-punctuation-full-stops-always-necessary-at-the-end)

Comment: There are no standards for punctuation in English, let alone in English headlines. You prints your paper and you takes your choice.

Comment: related: [**Where and why were capital letters first used in headlines?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116421/where-and-why-were-capital-letters-first-used-in-headlines) and [**Which words in a title should be capitalized?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized) and [**Capital letters in headlines**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92081/capital-letters-in-headlines)

Answer (score 4):

Headline writers usually feel free to violate any rule of grammar that will allow them to condense what they want to say to the space they have available. Punctuation takes up space and so will be used only where it is absolutely necessary to convey the meaning - or alternatively where a punctuation mark can be used instead of one or more words.

So for example, instead of:

> THE MINISTER SAID SOMETHING WOULD BE DONE.

The headline would be:

> MINISTER: SOMETHING WILL BE DONE

Or instead of:

> THE COMPANY WILL HIRE MORE WOMEN AND MINORITIES

we get:

> COMPANY TO HIRE MORE WOMEN, MINORITIES